# How to capture screenshot with zoomed out webview?

Tags: android

I have a webview with built in zoom-controls how to capture screenshot with full zoomed out webview and how to implement custom zoom in and out button.

Comment: get view drawing cache to bitmap than covert it to png

Comment: Please Can you send me the code?

Answer (score 0):

To get View's drawing cache you can use this code:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
     Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
     view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
     view.draw(canvas);
     return bmp;
}
```

Then convert bitmap to PNG/JPG:

```
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.png");
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
stream.close();
```

This should work.